# Facebook share issue when using FBShareDialog

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, facebook

I have followed the instruction for sharing the content on facebook.
My login code is below. I have successfully login using below code. But when i am pressed the share button it is open the dialogue in which it is default(Native) app and with different account sign in. Is there any problem in my code or is that issue with facebook?

```
let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    loginManager.loginBehavior = .SystemAccount
    loginManager.logInWithPublishPermissions(["publish_actions"] , fromViewController: fromController) { (result, error) in

        if (error != nil)
        {
         completion (response: nil, error: error)
        }
        else if result.isCancelled
        {
            let errorMessage = NSError(domain: "Facebook Login cancelled", code: -1, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "Facebook login got cancelled"])
            print("Login cancelled")
            completion(response: errorMessage, error: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            completion(response: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "Login Successfully"], error: nil)
        }

    }
```

This my sharing code :

```
let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()

    if (accessToken != nil)
    {
        if(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().hasGranted("publish_actions"))
        {
            let fbCOntent = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
            fbCOntent.contentURL = NSURL(string: "https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers");

            // TODO: publish content.
            let dialog = FBSDKShareDialog()

            dialog.fromViewController = self
            dialog.shareContent = fbCOntent
            dialog.mode = .Native

            if !(dialog.canShow())
            {
                dialog.mode = .FeedWeb
            }
            dialog.show()

        }
        else {
            // login with publish permission
        }
    }
```

Comment: you mean to say a share dialogue is open with different account not with current login acoount ???

Comment: Yes. I have login in my app with one account and in native fb application with different account so instead of opne dialogue with current login in the "Myapp" account it is showing the native fb app account.